# Git clone failing on public key. Is there something I'm missing?

Tags: linux, git, ssh, public-key

Due to Bundle install choking on libv8 dependency from theRubyRacer, JSON and other gems on a win 7 I'm trying to install and get running with Ubuntu.  Copied over .gitconfig and .ssh/rsa_id and .ssh/rsa_id.pub files, but trying a git clone of a private repo, works on win7 but fails (with same public key) on linux:

```
james@ubuntu:/documents/projects/$ sudo git clone git@github.com:the_project/back_end
[sudo] password for james: 
Cloning into back_end...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

vs win7's:

```
C:\test>git clone git@github.com:the_project/back_end
Cloning into back_end...
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/AJames/.shh/id_rsa':
remote: Counting objects: 10034, done.
```

any ideas?  Thank you!!

Comment: AJP, I've removed the "explicit solution" you edited into Amber's answer. Even if, for some unfathomable reason, you're OK with your projects directory being world-readable-and-writable, leaving a command like `chmod 777` in an answer without explanation as to its effects and dangers for any newbie to come upon is recklessness at its worst.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `sudo` would cause it to try to use `root`'s SSH key, not your own.

You probably really should either grant yourself access to the directory you're cloning into, or clone into a directory you already have access to.

Comment: I use root in my system to run "bundle install". Root has access everywhere, but I have the same problem. What happens?

Comment: It's not an access issue, it's that it's trying to use root's ssh key rather than your own.